# Find the value of $1/i+1/i^2+1/i^3+1/i^4+1/i^5+1/i^6+1/i^7+1/i^8+1/i^9$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I am trying to find the value of $$A=1/i+1/i^2+1/i^3+1/i^4+1/i^5+1/i^6+1/i^7+1/i^8+1/i^9$$
The answer is that $A=-1$, but I got that $A=\dfrac{1}{i}$. Where am I wrong? We have $$A=\dfrac{1}{i}+\dfrac{1}{-1}+\dfrac{1}{-i}+\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{i}+\dfrac{1}{-1}+\dfrac{1}{-i}+\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{i}=\dfrac{1}{i}$$

Comment: In general. $\frac{1}{i^{4n}}=1, \frac{1}{i^{4n+1}}=-i, \frac{1}{i^{4n+2}}=-1, \frac{1}{i^{4n+3}}=i$.

Comment: I dont know if it is a mistake or not, but the eight element is diferentent $i/i^8$ instead of $1/i^8$. Maybe that is where your mistake come from.

Comment: @Marcos, technical mistake, sorry.

Comment: Yep, likely a typo. Anyways, with my above statement, any 4 consecutive terms in the above series add up to 0. Which makes the answer $\frac{1}{i}$, or equivalently, $-i$.

Comment: Then there is nothing wrong in your solution

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{i} = -i$ . So the answer can be presented as $\frac{1}{i}$  or $-i$.

Comment: Another simple way to find the answer
\begin{align*}
 A & =\dfrac{1}{i}+\dfrac{1}{-1}+\dfrac{1}{-i}+\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{i}+\dfrac{1}{-1}+\dfrac{1}{-i}+\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{i} = \\
&= -i -1 +i +1 -i -1 +i +1 -i = \\
& = -i = \dfrac{1}{i}
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you mean to write that their answer is $A = -i$, not $A = -1$?

Comment: @user965851 did my answer help you ? if so , can you acept it ?

Answer (score 1):

HINT = $$\frac{1- (\frac{1}{i})^{10}}{1- (\frac{1}{i})}-1=\frac{1-(-i)^{10}}{1-(-i)}-1= \text{your expression}=-i=\frac{1}{i}$$ So ,your answer is correct

Comment: I think let's just substitute $\frac{1}{i}=-i$. Also their answer IS correct.

Comment: @Prometheus yes , it can be done , but this is just a hint for OP

Answer (score -2):

A is a geometric sequence its base is q=e to the power of pi/2 ×i so if we use the sum law we get
A= 1/i × 1-q⁹ / 1-q = 1/i × 1+i/1+i = 1/i
So I think your answer is correct

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: While technically correct, this is a terrible way to deal with this particular problem.

Comment: You're right, but I was proving that his answer is right in in a different way